# groovy create new xml node

Tags: xml, groovy

I'd like to create a simple xml node and I looked at the doc from http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html and write these codes.

```
    def newbook = new Node(null, 'book', [id:'3'])
    newbook.appendNode(new Node(newbook,'title',[id:'BookId3']))
    newbook.appendNode(new Node(newbook,'author',[id:'3'],'Harper Lee'))

    println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(newbook)
```

but the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><book id="3">
  <title id="BookId3"/>
  <title/>
  <author id="3">Harper Lee</author>
  <author/>
</book>
```

it seems to me there are two title tags and author tags get created.  why?

I have also tried

```
    def newbook = new Node(null, 'book', [id:'3'])
    newbook.appendNode(new QName('title'),'BookId3')
    newbook.appendNode(new QName('author'),[id:'3'],'Harper Lee')
    println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(newbook)
```

output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><book id="3">
  <title xmlns="">BookId3</title>
  <author xmlns="" id="3">Harper Lee</author>
</book>
```

now it looks good but is there a way to remove the namespace?

ideally i would like to have something like this

```
<book id="3">
  <title>BookId3</title>
  <author id="3">Harper Lee</author>
</book>
```

and then use it in the replaceNode() method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Groovy 2.4.5, this:

```
import groovy.util.*

def newbook = new Node(null, 'book', [id:'3'])

new Node(newbook,'title',[id:'BookId3'])
new Node(newbook,'author',[id:'3'],'Harper Lee')

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(newbook)
```

yields this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><book id="3">
  <title id="BookId3"/>
  <author id="3">Harper Lee</author>
</book>
```

It may not be obvious, but a closer reading of [the doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html) for the Node constructor reveals that it adds the node to the parent.

Comment: Yeah, you are adding two nodes essentially.  One with the constructor with those fields and one with a name it deciding is 'title' or 'author' with no attributes or value.