# Jenkins throwing an error when writing back an xml File

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a stage on my Jenkins pipeline where I search for a .xml File, open it, change a node and write the changes back to the .xml File. It works fine when I do it on my local machine but it does not work when it is done on Jenkins.

This is the code I'm using:

```
def inFile = new File('myFile.xml')
def xml = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parse( inFile )


if(xml.repositories.repository.url.toString().contains("string to match") {

    xml.repositories.repository.replaceNode { 
        repository{
            id("id")
            name("name")
            url("url")
        }
    }

    inFile.withWriter { outWriter ->
        XmlUtil.serialize(xml, outWriter )
    }
}
```

And Jenkins is showing this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'repository' found among steps[]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1172)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My xml file looks like this:

```
...

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>id old</id>
        <url>url old</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

...
```

I have check the imports and have them all correct. I moved the write part to a function and added @NonCPS annotation and nothing changed. I think I'm having a problem with the BufferedWriter but I don't know how to continue on this. Any help is welcome, thank you so much!

Comment: the `replaceNode` should be executed on the `repositories` object not the `repository` object. Try to use `xml.repositories.replaceNode { repository { ... } }`.

Comment: I have tried this and nothing changed, still same error. When trying this on my machine,  <repositories> object disappear . Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may not be a BufferedWriter, but more the reading part. The error message `No such DSL method 'repository' found among steps` points in that direction.

Line four of your code tries to access the XML object `repository` from your parsed `myFile.xml`:

```
if(xml.repositories.repository.url.toString().contains("string to match") {
```

Dereferencing `xml.respositories.repository` fails, maybe because the file can not be read or parsed. Can you check in your Groovy code, whether the file exists and is readable?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Yes, file exists and is readable. When I try to access
`if(xml.repositories.repository.url.toString().contains("string to match")` it returns the information correctly.

Comment: Can you add `echo xml.repositories.repository.getClass().getName()` after creating the XmlSlurper object? The build should output a class name for your repository object. Maybe you have an older Jenkins/Groovy version on your production Jenkins and `replaceNode` is not yet available?

Comment: As mentioned by @Sebastian Westemeyer the problem and the nature of the error shown by Jenkins points further. I'd say even more further - to line #8 of your code `repository{`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm following up on my comment with an actual solution advice:

`No such DSL method 'repository' found among steps` points to the fact that Jenkins is trying to interpret your `repository` as its *own* method. That could be happening actually on line `8` of your code as everywhere else it's explicitly defined what you're referencing.

So - in order to fix this ambiguity in your code, try this:

- Define your `repository` *node* variable and then use it within the `replaceNode` so it's crystal clear to Jenkins what it should do.

Something likes this (you'll probably need it import `groovy.util.Node` probably too (but I don't know the rest of you pipeline code) + adjust your node attributes according to your needs):

```
import groovy.util.*
def repository = new Node(null, 'repository', [id:'3'])

xml.repositories.repository.replaceNode { 
    repository
}
```

---

To provide some references and further inspiration (as myself I'm not a groovy master at all):

- I think this is the same exact root cause but with different method: [How To Use groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder in Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73803886/how-to-use-groovy-xml-streamingmarkupbuilder-in-jenkins-pipeline) (solution should be analogous)
- How to define own XML node within Jenkins, e.g.: [groovy create new xml node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415012/groovy-create-new-xml-node)
- The root case lies in CPS mismatch: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/)

  - So the alternative solution (depends on your pipeline code could be also to use `@NonCPS` annotation). An example covered on a blog (just found on the internet): http://tdongsi.github.io/blog/2017/06/07/groovy-in-jenkinsfile/
- `groovy.util.Node` docs: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html